# Is there a way to update HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in an c# application using web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Am using an ASP .Net application with anonymous authentication and need set the value for `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` in the `web.config` file so for each and every request the value needs to be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpContext.Current.User object is for .Net Frameworks integrated authentication framework only (using Forms- or Windows-Authentication) and can not be set programmatically.
If you need a value from the web.config in every request I would suggest to just read the value set in the web.config using

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]
```

Comment: How can i set filter in web.config file?

Comment: May I ask: what you actually trying to achieve? What you want to filter?